# Как проверить есть ли запись в таблице SQLite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, telegram-bot, aiogram

Создаю Телеграм бота на Python *(aiogram)*. Когда человек вводить команду */subs*, нужно проверить есть ли запись в таблице SQLite с его `telegram id`, если есть то изменить значение 2 полей, если нет то создать запись со всеми полями. Пока есть такой код:

```
@dp.message_handler(Command('subs'))
async def subs(message: Message):

    user_id = message['from']['id']
    await message.answer(" Спасибо за оформление подписки. Теперь вам доступен весь функционал бота! Введите команду /start что бы начать")
    try:
        db = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
        curs = db.cursor()

        curs.execute("BEGIN")
        curs.execute(f"SELECT id_telegram FROM users WHERE id_telegram = {user_id}")

        db.commit()

    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        if con: con.rollback()
        print("Ошибка при работе с SQLite", e)
    finally:
        if db:
            curs.close()
            print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проверка таблицы на наличие одной из записи проходит так:

```py
info = curs.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id_telegram=?', (user_id, ))
if info.fetchone() is None: 
        #Делаем когда нету человека в бд
else:
        #Делаем когда есть человек в бд
```

Answer (score 2):

Код написанный выше работает некорректно!

```
  if info.fetchone() is None: #условие никогда не выполнится
```

Я долго с этой темой мучился, вот рабочий код:

```
info = curs.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id_telegram=?', (user_id, )).fetchone()
#Если запрос вернул 0 строк, то...
if len(info) == 0: 
        return False
else:
        return True
```